# Reading values in an array .dat file

Tags: matlab, plot

I am having some trouble reading some data in .dat file using Matlab. I have data in .dat file as below;

```
# Dist  1.5 2.25    5.5 
1.0000  (0.0 0.0 0.0)   (1.22 1.33 1.45)    (6.11 7.31 7.00)    
2.0000  (0.0 0.0 0.0)   (3.01 5.66 3.88)    (9.22 5.00 5.00)
```

The goal is to be able load up the .dat file and do some post-processing by keeping the first row and first column as is then in the second, third and fourth columns read the second value in the each array. The output should be like;

```
# Dist  1.5 2.25    5.5 
1.0000  0.0     1.33    7.31
2.0000  0.0     5.66    5.00
```

I have used the following command

```
A5 =importdata('test.dat');
```

But it seems to create on column for all of the data. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try `help readtable`. There is enough flexibility in that function to do what you want.

Comment: Would appreciate an example!

Comment: Then you will really appreciate the documentation! RTFM!